# using ffmpeg, how would i be able to transfer/convert id3 tags (artist, track name, album art etc) from mp3 to oga (opus)?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, audio-conversion, id3

simple question, but i haven't found any simple answers (that worked). i would prefer to not have to apply them using different software, but if necessary, a batch converting `.sh` template would be appreciated. i have tried using `-map_metadata 0`, `-map_metadata 0:0,s0`, and `-map_metadata 0:s:0` and they all just give the same output as if i put nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer you want, but album art in ogg/oga/opus with `ffmpeg` is not possible yet:

- [#4448: Properly support cover art in ogg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4448)
- [#9044: Writing album art to ogg / opus files](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9044)

However, most of the tags should transfer with no need for `-map_metadata`. Make sure you're not using ancient `ffmpeg`.

Comment: i am using the latest version on debian atm, and all my tags go through. any other software available on debian is an option, as long as it can be put into an executable shell file, as this is also how i mass convert all my music into ogas. also, nonessential tidbit of information but i am using the libopus converter and not the opus encoder

Comment: i have now found out that you are wrong. using the official opus-tools package on debian buster, provided by xiph on opus-codec.org as well, includes `opusenc`, which has a `--picture` option that allows you to choose an image file (primarily of png variant). my only wish was to learn how to apply this to ffmpeg, as it's actual transcoding options are much more in depth and the transcoding seems to be more accurate than the official package

Comment: @JimmyBungalo What am I wrong about? I did not claim it is not possible to add album art to Opus. I only stated that it is not possible with ffmpeg according to the bug reports.

Comment: sorry, didn't read the ffmpeg part initially